# Query to get list of IDs that have records in the table

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDb table (named `Fruit`) with the following properties:

```
FruitId - string
CreatedDate - date
Type - number
Payload - blob
```

I also have a local list of strings `List<string> fruitIds;`.

I want to query the `Fruit` table and get only the Ids that have a corresponding record (i.e. exist) in the table.

What is a good way of doing that?  Right now, I am looping over each `Id` in `fruitIds` and making a separate query to DyanmoDb to see if I get a record back, if I do, I then save that Id to another local variable called `fruitIdsThatExistInDyanmoDb`.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public IQueryable <fruits> GetAllfruitsIDs() {
      return fruits.AsQueryable();
    }

    var data = GetAllfruitsIDs();

   // Or u can use this :
     public IEnumerable<fruits> GetAllfruitsIDs() {
              return fruits.AsQueryable().ToList;
            }

        var data = GetAllfruitsIDs();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq, its very simple, just check if item's FruitId is in fruitIds:

```
var result = fruits.Where(f => fruitIds.Contains(f.FruitId));
```

to save their Ids in a new local variable as you said:

```
List<string> fruitIdsThatExistInDyanmoDb = fruits.Where(f => fruitIds.Contains(f.FruitId))
             .Select(f=> f.FruitId).ToList();
```

Comment: Where is the DynamoDb query here?